# How do I configure CURL to use the same root certificates as Safari?

Tags: macos, security, command-line, ssl

It seems that CURL on OS X (10.10) is broken because it does not contain the same set of root SSL certificates as Safari.

Due to this it seems that there is a high chance for your to be unable to use curl with some HTTPS sites.

I observed that there is a guide on getting a list of certificates from 
http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem but this seems bad for two reasons:

- You are forced to get the certificates using HTTP instead of HTTPS so with minimal effort someone could give you a wrong list of certificates.
- These may get outdated and I would prefer to use the same set of root certificates as the rest of the OS.

What steps can be taken to get curl to match Safari when accessing web certificates?

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/a/394835

Comment: @AllInOne thanks for the link, clearly useful. Still, I am looking for a better solution, one that would make curl on OS X to behave similar to the browsers. I see no point on keeping the cacert in more than one place. Once we find a workaround, we can raise bugs with Apple to fix it.